# Adding records to Access from Excel - recordset is ReadOnly

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm putting together an Excel front-end with an Access database behind it, so that some of my colleagues can collate data from previous projects (without having to learn to use Access themselves!)

So I have a "Data" sheet in the Excel workbook that occasionally refreshes from the database, then a "Dashboard" sheet that allows filtering of that data.

Where I'm having trouble is in closing the loop - allowing input of new data into the database. The relevant code is below:

```
Private Sub btnDBImport_Click()

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim errorList As String 

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0"
    .ConnectionString = "\\FileAddress\DB.accdb"
    .Open
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open Source:="TableName", _
         ActiveConnection:=cn, _
         CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
         LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
         Options:=adCmdTableDirect


    If validationTest = False Then
        errorList = errorList & "Data at row " & i & " was not added to the database due to missing information." & vbCrLf
    Else
        rst.AddNew
        With rst
            .Fields(1) = Value1
            .Fields(2) = Value2
        End With
        rst.Update
    End If

Next i

If errorList <> "" Then
    MsgBox errorList, vbOKOnly, "Data error"
End If

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above is everything involved in defining, opening and working on a recordset; I get an error at rst.AddNew because "cannot update, database or object is ReadOnly".
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified if you can add records to the table via Access, or is the database potentially being set ReadOnly elsewhere?  Also, try `rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient` as Access is always running on the client.  It's something I've stumbled into as I think adUseServer can mess with your RecordCount property

Comment: Hm. Database is currently opening in Access as ReadOnly, so I'll have to see if I can get to the bottom of that. Thanks Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

So, with thanks to the comment from [Jimmy Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690141/jimmy-smith), I've got to the bottom of this, or at least fixed my immediate problem.

The table was being treated as ReadOnly both when accessed through MS Access directly and when loaded as a Recordset using VBA because there was a link to the table in the same Excel workbook.

Now that I've deleted the link to the table and instead update the records in it through code, I'm consistently getting requested levels of access to the relevant table and everything is working as intended. Time to commit to Rubberduck and show it to the userbase.